# How do I use an SVG in React without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

Tags: svg, reactjs

I've created a React component for the Facebook icon to be able to use in the footer. Unfortunately it doesn't work unless I use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, so the icon shows up - however it appears broken.

Here is the code for the Facebook component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Facebook extends React.Component{
 render() {
   var svgString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  --><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><div><span id="facebook"><svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652" style="enable-background:new 0 0 49.652 49.652;" xml:space="preserve" class="icon"><g><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" class="circle" fill="white"/><path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z" /></g></svg></span>'
   return (
     <div>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: svgString }} />
     </div>
   )
 }
};


export default Facebook;
```

and here is the code for the original SVG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<div>
  <span id="facebook">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652" style="enable-background:new 0 0 49.652 49.652;" xml:space="preserve" class="icon">
    <g>
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" class="circle" fill="white"/>
        <path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0,13.688,11.137,24.826,24.826,24.826c13.688,0,24.826-11.138,24.826-24.826
            C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845
            v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z
            " />
    </g>

  </svg>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the `file-loader` for webpack so that you may import the svg. Then you can just use the imported object as the `src` attribute of an image tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVGs should work natively in React, there's no need to set DOCTYPE and the XML encoding, version, or namespace (JSX is not XML, it is XML-like):

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652" style="enable-background:new 0 0 49.652 49.652;" className="icon">
        <g>
          <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" className="circle" fill="white"/>
          <path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0,13.688,11.137,24.826,24.826,24.826c13.688,0,24.826-11.138,24.826-24.826
            C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845
            v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z
          " />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Also make sure `class` is `className` instead.

Comment: this only works when you have svg markup to embed directly by hard coding.
this does not provide any ways to  render svg from server or loading dynamically from local

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which version of react your using right now

for CRA Version 3 -

you can simply do this - save your svg in different file like facebookIcon.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  --><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><div><span id="facebook"><svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652" style="enable-background:new 0 0 49.652 49.652;" xml:space="preserve" class="icon"><g><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" class="circle" fill="white"/><path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z" /></g></svg></span>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ReactComponent as fbIcon } from './facebookIcon.svg';

class Facebook extends React.Component{
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
      <fbIcon />
     </div>
   )
 }
};


export default Facebook;
```

for CRA Version 2 -
you can check this link - https://egghead.io/lessons/react-add-svgs-as-react-components-with-create-react-app-2-0

Comment: After searching the internet for hours for "react inline svg" your solution was the easiest and fastest

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like this [svg-to-jsx](https://github.com/janjakubnanista/svg-to-jsx)