# Render SVGSVGElement in React JS without dangerouslySetInnerHtml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, vis.js

**Question:**
Can I render an `SVGSVGElement` in React without using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`?

**Context:**

I am using the [vis.js](http://visjs.org/docs/graph2d/) graph library, the `getLegend` method returns an [`SVGSVGElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement) object i.e.
`const icon = chart.getLegend(args);`
In the console I can see this:

```
in: icon instanceof SVGSVGElement
out: true
in: icon
out: <svg><rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" class="vis-outline"></rect><path class="vis-graph-group0" d="M0,15 L30,15"></path></svg>
```

**Problem:**

When I try to render this in react using:

```
render (
<div> { icon } </div>
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object SVGSVGElement]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `LegendElement`
```

**Workaround:**

For now I am using:
`<svg dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: icon.innerHTML}} />`

But I was hoping for a straightforward solution that doesn't use a method with the word dangerous in the name.

**Research:**

I read this similar question but I don't think it helps for SVG generated at run time: [How do I use an SVG in React without using dangerouslySetInnerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035422/how-do-i-use-an-svg-in-react-without-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simple append the SVGSVGElement using a useRef like this. This example is for a functional component with hooks but can be adapted for class components.

```
const svg = useRef(null);
useEffect(()=>{
    if(svg.current){
        svg.current.appendChild(icon)
    } 
}, []);

return (
    <div ref={svg}/>
);
```

Comment: Thanks Ihsan,If anyone can verify this and let me know to mark the answer. I no longer have access to the project I needed this for and don't have time to set up a PoC :D

Comment: This sort of works, but the SVG is like squished until I click on it. But that is probably due to something else (I'm trying to get a directed force graph from D3 to render in there)

Comment: I finally got the chance to validate this answer and it works perfectly at least in my case. Thanks Ishan!

Comment: @Asu; did you ever get this to work for your force graph? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Xari Yes, I had to add this just before render's return statement: `if (d3Chart.simulation && d3Chart.simulation.restart) {d3Chart.simulation.restart();}`

Comment: It rendered two `svg` icons. So, I changed the `if` condition like this. `if (svg.current && (svg.current as any).innerHTML === "")`

Answer (score 0):

During development, it is very common to re-render the svg, so I had to do this:

```
  const icon = (...); // SVGSVGElement
  const svg = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (svg.current) {
      if (svg.current.firstChild) {
        svg.current.replaceChild(icon, svg.current.firstChild)
      } else {
        svg.current.appendChild(icon)
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return <div ref={svg} />
```

This code prevents from rendering 2+ times.